# File not getting created during second MR

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a hadoop implementation for an algorithm.

I am doing it in Eclipse:
When i run in eclipse my algorithm works fine and creates necessary files and output.

```
Algorithm
       |
       |___creates a file0.txt file.
       |
       |___creates a file1.txt file.
       |
       |___creates a file3.txt file.
       |
       |___creates a file4.txt file.
       |
       |___creates a file5.txt file.
       |
       |___creates a file6.txt file.
       |
       |___creates a file7.txt file.
```

Completes the job.
When i tried my program in Hadoop cluster except file0.txt all other files are not getting created in `hdfs` from  reducer phase.

Do any one gone through this issue.

Pls help.
[Source](https://github.com/studhadoop/Reference)

[Output from eclipse](https://github.com/studhadoop/Execution/blob/master/output/originaleclipseoutput)

[Output from cluster](https://github.com/studhadoop/Execution/blob/master/output/originalclusteroutput)

Answer (score 0):

The output file is specified by the Driver code, irrespective of the MR job. Please check your  Driver code or share it here

Comment: added link in question

Comment: In your C45.java which I believe is your driver code in line 265 you are specifying your output path. This is going to be same for all map reduce job. If you want different out put paths, you need to run different jobs with different conf

Comment: My programs executes successfully in eclipse. but it is failing in cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is slightly confusing. All I understand is that you have 413 bytes long file and you are trying to run 7 MR jobs. 
So, are you saying you have 7 pairs of **Mapper** and **Reducer** classes that you want to run on that 413 byte file ? 
Again you mentioned `my algorithm runs different MR jobs depending upon the data sets` , so I'm left to assume that a dataset gets to be used only by one pair of Mapper-Reducer class. Did you verify that your dataset satisfies the condition for Mapper-Reducer pair 1,3,4,5,6,7,

Are all these Mapper-Reducer pair using same output folder... ? That might also be big concern.

Please answer them , then possibly I can help.

Comment: So you have only one pair of Mapper-Reducer. Ok, so...all that you mentioned above doesn't make much sense to me now. How are you running 7 jobs with one mapper/reducer. Are you expecting 7 tasks ? The file size is too small...what's the split size and block size ? I think the current behavior is fine due to small size of file.

Comment: javadevg actually my code is only runnning within eclipse.But when i export them to my cluster and run them my program is showing error:(

Comment: javadevg i think i explained my doubt in a wrong way. I updated my question. but i have a doubt [link](https://github.com/studhadoop/Execution/blob/master/output/originaleclipseoutput) what is that. different MR or different task execution.Normally when i am running WordCount i am getting only one such block ie before next "In map'.